# How can I compile Java code in Windows without installing the whole JDK?

Tags: java, compilation

Let’s say the runtime environment (version 1.6.0_01-b06) is already in place, but since I lack administrative privileges in this particular PC, the JDK can’t be installed. So, is there any portable JDK or standalone Java compiler for Windows that doesn’t require installation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might try taking the tools.jar file from the JDK (you would have to copy it over from another machine) and see if that worked.

javac is essentially a small exe that starts the VM with the specific class for the compiler.

Also, there is nothing (that I am aware of) about the JDK install that you couldn't do with a copy of it from another machine.  So get on a machine you can install the JDK on, install it, and then copy the files to a place on the machine that you lack the rights to and it should work.

Comment: This is so true.. I remember when my internet connection was still an expensive dial-up (which gives away my age...) I copied the jdk's bin dir from a friend on 1.44 diskettes! And of course it worked perfectly =8-)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to install JDK. Just copy it over from another machine, and set PATH to %jdk%/bin and JAVA_HOME to %jdk% (actually, only PATH is often enough). I do it all the time.

Comment: If he doesn't have administrative privilege, that means he also doesn't have the privilege to change **environmental variables**.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse works very well. being a portable ide, it will use it's own jdk. I personally use jGrasp w/ the jdk's folder as a PATH when I'm trying to write something quick.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Jikes](http://jikes.sourceforge.net/).