# How to run `ant` build-script without setting any environment variable?

Tags: java, ant, build, jar, build-process

I would like to run the `ant` build-script without installing `Java` and setting any environment variable like `path`, `JAVA_HOME` & `ANT_HOME` to environment variable.

I have copied already installed folders of `Jdk-1.7u17`, `Jre-1.7u17` and `apache-ant-1.9.0` from one machine to another machine into `C:\buildscript_required_files_v2` folder.

Now i have a window batch file that gets into the path where build.xml resides and run `ant`

```
cd VersionBuild
C:\buildscript_required_files_v2\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin\ant
```

build.xml complies the Java class and creates a Jar file.

```
<project name="VersionBuild"  default="clean" basedir=".">
    <description>
        simple example build file
    </description>

  <!-- set global properties for this build -->


  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->


 </target>

 <target name="CompilingBuildversion" depends="init"
        description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <C:\buildscript_required_files_v2\java\jdk64\bin\javac.exe srcdir="." destdir="."/>
  </target>

  <target name="Creating jar" depends="CompilingBuildversion">
      <jar jarfile="VersionBuild.jar"  basedir="."/>
 </target>    


 <target name="clean" depends="Creating jar">

 </target>

</project>
```

when I am running that bach file, I am getting the following exception -

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li
b\tools.jar
```

Can I run `ant` build-script without installing `Java` and setting any environment variable? Can i specify `JAVA_HOME` for ant locally into the `build.xml` so `ant` can take refrence from `C:\buildscript_required_files_v2` folder?

Comment: `ant` is a `Java` library.

Comment: if i am not wrong, tools.jar should be in a JDK not a JRE, you should be pointing to the JDK. If you are asking on how to change that, ignore this comment.

Comment: how can you run a Java program without installing Java, that doesn't make sense?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson You can run java program without installing java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624950/how-can-i-compile-java-code-in-windows-without-installing-the-whole-jdk

Comment: @AshishPancholi that is still considered installing Java, even if you don't use the official installer, you still need the runtime, you can't run a Java program without the runtime.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson FYI: You can run without installing java.

Comment: @AshishPancholi, you are arguing semantics.  A Java runtime is required for a Java program to be executed.  How that Java runtime is acquired is a different matter.

Comment: @SimonC okay. so you mean to say it is not possible to run ant build-script without installing Java and without setting any environment variable. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is not concerned with *_HOME variables, but I first answer you question.
Yes you can.

Just configure your PATH variable to (1) dir where java.exe resides (2) where ant.bat resides.
In case when *_HOME defined the path can be written:

```
PATH=...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%
```

Since you have no such variables you need declare:

```
PATH=...;C:\Program Files\Java\bin;c:\ant\bin
```

But in real you problem that you try use JRE while ant needs JDK. Just download from oracle site. `tools.jar` is part of JDK but not JRE.

**UPDATE**: 
You can write you own bat file that lets Windows know where to locate `.exe` and `.bat` files. Just create in notepad text file named `my-ant.bat` And place following there:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\buildscript_required_files_v2\java\jdk64
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\buildscript_required_files_v2\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin
rem ** Now we invoke ant **
ant
```

Obviously you would like manipulate with command line arguments. That is why instead of last `ant` line use following:

```
set my_ant_start=
:setupArgs
if ""%1""=="""" goto doneStart
set my_ant_start=%my_ant_start% %1
shift
goto setupArgs
:doneStart
rem ** Now we invoke ant **
ant %my_ant_start%
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not specifying path of JRE any where as you can see in build.xml and bat file, I have nowhere specify the path. I am compling my source code using jdk and it automatically searching tool.jar into jre.

Comment: Actually I do not want to set any thing to environment variable even into the path. Is there any other way?

Comment: @AshishPancholi if you install JDK correctly it have automatically patch PATH variable. Otherwise windows cannot find where to locate `.exe` or `.bat` files. Instead you can write you own `my-ant.bat` file that in first line set path (locally for this `.bat`) and after that starts your `ant` process

Comment: Thanks again. As you said - "you can write you own my-ant.bat file that in first line set path (locally for this .bat)" - Please suggest how can set those path? what that bat file will contain? where it will set the path?

Comment: Thanks. when we run my-ant.bat it sets the path to environment variable and clear/reset again when closed the cmd window. I was not aware of this.